# Does DBCC SHRINKDATABASE free physical disk space during its run?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, shrink

I want to run exactly this command:

```
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE mydb
```

When I run this just for a while and then kill it, will the physical database file be a little bit smaller?

In other words: Does the command immediatedly free physical disk space during its run, or does it first a full reorganization, and only then free all physical space?

EDIT: We have simple recovery model, so our log file is very small and we only have one big database file.

Answer (score 2):

DBCC SHRINKDATABASE does not rollback when the process is killed so theoretically you'd be able to run it for a period of a time, kill the process, and have some reclaimed space (assuming there is any that can be reclaimed). See [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8e1c1474-896d-4574-adf4-e1a2c621f0a4/abort-a-dbcc-shrinkdatabase?forum=sqlgetstarted#:%7E:text=4.,start%20from%20where%20it%20left.) for more information.

Also please see and research the warnings I provided against shrinking in my answer to your other [StackExchange question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/281502/is-dbcc-shrinkfile-better-than-dbcc-shrinkdatabase).

> ...[it's] heavy operations, generally nonsensical to do because if
> they grew to a certain size they'll likely grow back to that size soon
> anyway and a growth operation is also heavy, and shrinking any
> database files (except Temporary) does have a small risk of data
> corruption.

Comment: Thanks for the 1st paragraph. The 2nd paragraph does not apply to us. We had an abnormal operation which wasted space.

Comment: @askolotl No problem. I've been there (abnormal space wasting operation) and the experts still provided me the same warnings I'm passing on to you. I would be lying if I didn't say I still used the occasional shrink once in a blue moon anyway, but it's still important to be aware of the warnings, especially with potential data loss when shrinking the MDF.